# ImageMagik convert command on Windows 2008

Tags: php, windows, exec

I am trying to execute a simple ImageMagick convert command from a php script, i can convert the same files and achieve the results via command prompt but in php i am unable to execute the same command by any means , the code is :

```
exec('convert -density 350 '.__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'test.pdf '. __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'image.png');
```

and this error is thrown by php

> convert.exe: no decode delegate for this image format
>   'C:\XAMPP\htdocs\test.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
>   convert.exe: missing an image filename 'C:\XAMPP\htdocs\image.png' @
>   error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3016.

With same configuration on a Windows 7 x64 i can execute and achieve the result, but on windows 2008 R2 i am unable, what could be the cause for this?

Comment: Does the same command work for non-pdf files?

Comment: No, it gives same error for all type even JPEG to PNG conversions!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so solution was quite simple and straightforward, you just need to make sure that the permissions on C:\Windows\Temp and to that of Imagick "CONVERT.EXE" folder are set to "EVERYONE -> ALL" So , group everyone has permissions of doing what soever with the convert and Temp folder.

Hope it helps.